# Watch-your-step model with StellarGraph is not working on a GPU

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, gpu, stellargraph

I am trying to train a large graph-embedding using WatchYourStep algorithm using StellarGraph.

For some reason, the model is only trained on a CPU a**nd not utilizing the GPUs**.
using:

- TensorFlow-gpu 2.3.1
- having 2 GPUs , cuda 10.1
- running inside an nvidia-docker container.
- I know that tesnorflow do find the GPUs.  (`tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)`)
- I have tried to run under `with tf.device('/GPU:0'):`
- I have tried to run it with `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`.
- Tried to uninstall tensorflow and reinstall tensorflow-gpu.

Nevertheless, when running **nvidia-smi**, I don't see any activity on the GPUs, and the training is very slow.
How to debug this?

```py
def watch_your_step_model():
    '''use the config to geenrate the WatchYourStep model'''
    cfg = load_config()
    generator           = generator_for_watch_your_step()
    num_walks           = cfg['num_walks']
    embedding_dimension = cfg['embedding_dimension']
    learning_rate       = cfg['learning_rate']
    
    wys = WatchYourStep(
        generator,
        num_walks=num_walks,
        embedding_dimension=embedding_dimension,
        attention_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.5),
    )
    
    x_in, x_out = wys.in_out_tensors()
    model = Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=x_out)
    model.compile(loss=graph_log_likelihood, optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate))
    return model, generator, wys

def train_watch_your_step_model(epochs = 3000):
    cfg = load_config()
    batch_size      = cfg['batch_size']
    steps_per_epoch = cfg['steps_per_epoch']
    callbacks, checkpoint_file = watch_your_step_callbacks(cfg)
    
    # strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
    # print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))
    # with strategy.scope():
    
    model, generator, wys = watch_your_step_model()

    train_gen = generator.flow(batch_size=batch_size, num_parallel_calls=8)
    train_gen.prefetch(20480000)

    history = model.fit(
        train_gen, 
        epochs=epochs, 
        verbose=1, 
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        callbacks = callbacks
    )
     
    copy_last_trained_wys_weights_to_data()
    
    return history, checkpoint_file

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    train_watch_your_step_model()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just followed this instructions : https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/issues/546.

It worked for me.

Basically you have to edit the file setup.py from stellargraph github and remove the tensorflow requirement (line 25 and 27 https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/blob/develop/setup.py) .